# reset \subsection between \section*

Tags: sectioning

For some reasons, I want to use `\section*` in my document, but since I also use `\subsection`, they don't get refreshed. To be more specific:

​

```
\section*{AA}
\subsection{aa}
\subsection{aaa}
\subsection{aaaa}
\subsection{aaaaa}
\section*{BB}
\subsection{bb}
\subsection{bbb}
\subsection{bbbb}
\subsection{bbbb}
```

will produce this:

[image]

How do I make sure that `\subsection` get restarted between `\section*`? The subsections under AA and BB should start from 1.

EDIT: The section prefix should preferably be gone.

Comment: Try `\setcounter{subsection}{0}` after `\section*{BB}`.

Comment: Where does the `2` comes from?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Just quickly used Overleaf to create the case... probably from previous sections...

Comment: But in your document will it be there too or do you want to number the subsection without this prefix?

Comment: preferably without the prefix - I will update the question.

Comment: Is *every* section specified with `\section*`?

Comment: @egreg at the moment yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If *all* sections are unnumbered, this seems to be the simplest solution: remove the number from the section title.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{%
  \ifcsname specialformat#1\endcsname
    \csname specialformat#1\endcsname
  \else
    \csname the#1\endcsname\quad % default
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\specialformatsection}{}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}

\begin{document}

\section{AA}
\subsection{aa}
\subsection{aaa}
\subsection{aaaa}
\subsection{aaaaa}
\section{BB}
\subsection{bb}
\subsection{bbb}
\subsection{bbbb}
\subsection{bbbb}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that you have to use `\section`, rather than `\section*`.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `\setcounter{section}` or `\setcounter{subsection}`, depending on your need.

```
\section*{AA}
\setcounter{section}{1}
\subsection{aa}
\subsection{aaa}
\subsection{aaaa}
\subsection{aaaaa}
\section*{BB}
\setcounter{section}{2}
\subsection{bb}
\subsection{bbb}
\subsection{bbbb}
\subsection{bbbb}
```